# Dynamically concat the dataframe columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have list of dataframe column names which I need to concat (list_name=["name","email"]) and I have a dataframe with many columns(df="name","email","address","phone"). Now I need to concat and create a new column for the values of names specified in list.

Expected result: df="name","email","address","phone","nameemail"

List=["name","email"]. But the list is dynamic(it may have n number of values)

**df**

| name | email | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ram | ram@gmail.com | 345897045 |
| raj | raj@gmail.com | 658086657 |

**expexteddf**

| name | email | phone | nameemail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ram | ram@gmail.com | 345897045 | ramram@gmail.com |
| raj | raj@gmail.com | 658086657 | rajraj@gmail.com |

Answer (score 1):

This should be straightforward using `concat` function. You should at least try and show what you did, but this should be way to go:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat
val concatColumns = ... // List of column names to concatenate
val newColumnName = concatColumns.mkString
expexteddf = df.addColumn(newColumnName, concat(concatColumns: _*))
```